# How do I permanently change the terminal prompt in iTerm2 using zsh?

Tags: unix, command-line, terminal, command-prompt, zsh

In the terminal prompt under the Default profile this shows:

```
Last login: Sat Jun 21 17:43:00 on ttys000
➜  ~
```

When I type:

```
➜  ~  export PS1="|%*| ~ "
```

I receive this:

```
|17:44:11| ~
```

That's what I want displayed. How do i make this permanent, so I won't have to type this every time?

I have tried the following: inserting `export PS1="|%*| ~ "` into `.zsh`, also under Prefrences >> Profile >> CustomeTheme and Default >> Command >> checked command I inserted `export PS1="|%*| ~ "` with no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with iTerm2; it's purely a zsh issue.

You need to add the command

```
PS1="|%*| ~ "
```

to your `$HOME/.zshrc` file.

Followup based on the comments: Your best bet is to add this line at or near the *end* of your `.zshrc` file. If something else in `.zshrc` is settings `$PS`, either directly or indirectly (by invoking another script), you want your desired value to override that.

There's no need to `export` the value of `$PS1`.

There are probably other places you could put the command.  See the [zsh manual](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Files.html#Startup_002fShutdown-Files) (or type `info zsh`) for more details. As far as I can tell, zsh doesn't pay attention to a `.zsh` file (unless you specifically tell it to).

Comment: Thanks for the tips. However, it keeps the same output as I posted on my original question. Following your instructions I typed: `open $HOME/.zshrc` i then added `PS1="|%*| ~ "` then restarted iTerm.

Comment: @JonaTheApprentice: I don't use MacOS; what does `open` do? Did you save the file after editing it? IF you temporarily add `echo hello` to your `.zshrc`, does it appear when you start `zsh`? Are you sure `zsh` is your default shell?

Comment: `open [filename]` opens the file to the default text editor. I did save the file after editing. `echo hello` does appear when I restart the terminal. zsh is my default shell, I ran `chsh -s /bin/zsh` and no changes were made confirming that it is default.

Comment: What does `echo "$PS1"` print? Grasping at straws, did you spell `PS1` correctly?

Comment: In .zshrc the first line is `PS1="|%*| ~ "`
(New line)
`➜  ~  echo "$PS1"
${ret_status}%{$fg_bold[green]%}%p %{$fg[cyan]%}%c %{$fg_bold[blue]%}$(git_prompt_info)%{$fg_bold[blue]%} % %{$reset_color%}`

Comment: If adding `echo hello` to `.zshrc` makes it print `hello`, then your `.zshrc` is being executed. You're setting `$PS1` in `.zshrc`. Something else must be assigning a new value to it. Read the zsh documentation carefully to see what else might be executed, and check the rest of your `.zshrc` for anything else that might be setting `$PS1`. Your best bet may be to move the `PS1="|%*| ~ "` command to the *end* of your `.zshrc`.

Comment: Moving `PS1="|%*| ~ "` to the very end did it. Thanks!

Comment: Then the problem is that something else in your `.zshrc` is setting `$PS1`, either directly or by invoking another script. It would be worth tracking that down. I've updated my answer.